# Django Gramps no module named web.settings

Tags: django, ubuntu

I'm using Gramps 3.3.1 under Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to in Django Export/Import. The install is okay, but when I look at the installed addons, it says that it failed, with reason: "No module named web.settings".

I cann't for the life of me figure out how to fix this. I'm assuming that it's this line in the python script:

```
import web.settings as default_settings
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm trying to get this data out and into a MySQL database, but I can't seem to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you run into an error where Python tells you "No module named blah" it really means it can't find "blah".

I would check your pythonpath and the filesystem permissions on the stuff in your path.

*Edit*

Your issue seems to be a known issue: http://www.gramps-project.org/bugs/view.php?id=5464

It's caused by not running Gramps from source, near as I can tell. It doesn't look like a Python Path issue, so much as the Gramps Django devs making assumptions where your Django settings would be (but I could be wrong).

As for Python Path, there's plenty of resources describing how to. The simplest way to check your Python path is to run `echo $PYTHONPATH` in a terminal. If you don't see it there, Python might not find it.

Comment: How would I then add this module to the path? I'm not even sure where it is stored on my machine.